# reject-regex with wget

Tags: regex, wget

mirroring a site with wget, i need to get out of an infinite loop of a dynamic web site calendar.
basically i should need to mirror all the site

```
http://{site}/
```

but reject from mirroring all urls in this path:

```
http://{site}/calendar/
```

except from

```
http://{site}/calendar/2014-10
http://{site}/calendar/2014-11
```

how to to use --reject-regex?
if i run something like:

```
ACCEPT='.*(?!/calendar).*|.*calendar/2014-1[01].*'
wget -r -p --accept-regex=$ACCEPT http://{site}
```

i got this error: Invalid preceding regular expression

Answer (score 1):

I guess you figured this out, but you have to put $ACCEPT in single quotes. The variable doesn't contain the necessary quotes.

`wget -r -p --accept-regex='$ACCEPT' http://{site}`